# log4Net logging improper message

Tags: oracle, log4net

I've deployed log4Net on 2 different servers. on 1st its showing proper message like:

[ERROR] [2018-01-25 19:17:00,856] [MANSOUR3185] [GicCipDataObjects.Oracle] [GetAllRequest] - DB Error
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-01722: **invalid number**

but on 2nd server it is not logging proper message:

[ERROR] [2018-01-25 19:17:00,856] [MANSOUR3185] [GicCipDataObjects.Oracle] [GetAllRequest] - DB Error
System.Data.OracleClient.OracleException (0x80131938): ORA-01722: **ÑÞã ÛíÑ ÕÇáÍ**

I've highlighted both. configuration is same on both servers. Need help.

Comment: Interesting. That's not an actual language, obviously, and if it's mojibake I'm not sure what manner of encoding mapping would be the problem. This does not look like a problem in log4net, though, but something to do with the Oracle driver. Tagging this as such just in case Oracle experts have seen this before.

Comment: Narrow down any other possible differences -- .NET Framework, Oracle driver version, software version, 32-bit vs. 64-bit, OS, third party firewall/network drivers, etc. *Something* is different, so that the configuration is the same is not the relevant bit.

Comment: Namespace `System.Data.OracleClient` is [deprecated](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/oracle-and-adonet) for ages. Consider to use an up-to-date provider from Oracle.

Comment: Try to add `Unicode=true` to ConnectionString.

Comment: Thanks JeroenMostert and WernfriedDomscheit. Unfortunately this problem comes only for live application environment instead of beta environment. So ill consider above suggestions in my next live application release.  I hope its  helps.